# using jquery isotope for sorting combined with slideToggle divs

Tags: jquery, css, sorting, jquery-isotope, slidetoggle

I'm working on a new website.
I have many parrent divs each having a chlid divs hidden, when clicking on the parrent divs, chlidren div is shown using slideToggle, it works perfectly fine, very simple code.

here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mmk933wf/4/

here is my HTML :

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="bloc_artiste" id="peter_christopherson_aka_sleazy" data-date-created="2010" data-artist="christopherson aka sleazy" data-band="throbbing gristle, coil, ptv">
        <table class="ligne_info">
            <tr>
                <td class="artist"><span class="artist_DSC" style="display:none">christopherson aka sleazy</span>
                    peter christopherson aka sleazy
                </td>
                <td class="band"><span class="band_DSC" style="display:none">throbbing gristle, coil, ptv</span>
                    throbbing gristle, coil, ptv
                </td>
                <td class="year">

                    <span class="year_DSC" style="display:none">        2010</span>
                    2010</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="bloc_top_ten">

            <p class="italic">Nowadays, I rarely use music in the way I did when I was a young - as a palliative, a tranquilliser, wallpaper to cover over uncomfortable or embarrassing cracks in the passage of life. At the age of 50 I have come to prefer the silence, or rather<p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bloc_artiste" id="chris_carter" data-date-created="2009" 

            data-artist="carter" data-band="throbbing gristle / chris and cosey">
                <table class="ligne_info">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="artist"><span class="artist_DSC" style="display:none">carter</span>
                            chris carter
                        </td>
                        <td class="band"><span class="band_DSC" style="display:none">throbbing gristle / chris and cosey</span>
                            throbbing gristle / chris and cosey
                        </td>
                        <td class="year">

                            <span class="year_DSC" style="display:none">        2009</span>
                            2009</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="bloc_top_ten">

                    <p class="italic">I&#039;ve been playing these albums regularly for many years, first on tape and vinyl, then CD and now on my iPod. They are listed in order of release date, not in any order of preference.<p>

                        <h1>pennies from heaven compilation - various artists (original 1929-1938 version)  </h1><br>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="bloc_artiste" id="ian_svenonius" data-date-created="2010" 

                        data-artist="svenonius" data-band="the make up">
                            <table class="ligne_info">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="artist"><span class="artist_DSC" style="display:none">svenonius</span>
                                        ian svenonius
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="band"><span class="band_DSC" style="display:none">the make up</span>
                                        the make up
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="year">

                                        <span class="year_DSC" style="display:none">        2010</span>
                                        2010</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class="bloc_top_ten">



                                <h1>short novel - by ian  </h1><br>
                                <p><p>&laquo;&nbsp;The Creatures&nbsp;&raquo; were standing in groups 3 or 4 deep, throughout the park at the intersection of 12th street and Hilliard place.</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

my CSS :

```
.bloc_artiste{width:100%;}
.bloc_top_ten {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: none;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

and my JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ligne_open();
});

function ligne_open(){
    $('.bloc_artiste').click(function () {
        var ID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).siblings().children().next().slideUp(500);
        $(this).children().next('div').slideToggle(500, function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(ID).offset().top
            }, 500);
        });

        $(this).siblings().children().next().slideUp(500);
        return false;

    });

    $('.bloc_artiste').hover(function(){
        $('.bloc_artiste').not(this).css('opacity','0.4');
    },function(){
        $('.bloc_artiste').not(this).css('opacity','1');
    });   
}
```

now I want to be abble to sort my divs using data-sort-value, so I found that jquery isotope is fine for this. I've installed the jquery plugin, and edited my code. works fine too to sort my divs using multiple sorting date.

here is a jsfiddle with isotope : http://jsfiddle.net/4m0oL1zh/1/

my HTML :

```
<table class="ligne_libelle">
    <tr>
        <td class="artist">
            ARTIST 
            <span class="sorts">
                <span class="button" data-sort-value="artist">&#x25B2;</span>
                <span class="button" data-sort-value="artist_DSC">&#x25BC;</span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="band">
            BAND
            <span class="sorts">
                <span class="button" data-sort-value="band">&#x25B2;</span>
                <span class="button" data-sort-value="band_DSC">&#x25BC;</span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="year">
            YEAR
            <span class="sorts">
                <span class="button" data-sort-value="year">&#x25B2;</span>
                <span class="button" data-sort-value="year_DSC">&#x25BC;</span>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="content">
    <div class="bloc_artiste" id="peter_christopherson_aka_sleazy" data-date-created="2010" data-artist="christopherson aka sleazy" data-band="throbbing gristle, coil, ptv">
        <table class="ligne_info">
            <tr>
                <td class="artist"><span class="artist_DSC" style="display:none">christopherson aka sleazy</span>
                    peter christopherson aka sleazy
                </td>
                <td class="band"><span class="band_DSC" style="display:none">throbbing gristle, coil, ptv</span>
                    throbbing gristle, coil, ptv
                </td>
                <td class="year">

                    <span class="year_DSC" style="display:none">        2010</span>
                    2010</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="bloc_top_ten">

            <p class="italic">Nowadays, I rarely use music in the way I did when I was a young - as a palliative, a tranquilliser, wallpaper to cover over uncomfortable or embarrassing cracks in the passage of life. At the age of 50 I have come to prefer the silence, or rather<p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bloc_artiste" id="chris_carter" data-date-created="2009" 

            data-artist="carter" data-band="throbbing gristle / chris and cosey">
                <table class="ligne_info">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="artist"><span class="artist_DSC" style="display:none">carter</span>
                            chris carter
                        </td>
                        <td class="band"><span class="band_DSC" style="display:none">throbbing gristle / chris and cosey</span>
                            throbbing gristle / chris and cosey
                        </td>
                        <td class="year">

                            <span class="year_DSC" style="display:none">        2009</span>
                            2009</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="bloc_top_ten">

                    <p class="italic">I&#039;ve been playing these albums regularly for many years, first on tape and vinyl, then CD and now on my iPod. They are listed in order of release date, not in any order of preference.<p>

                        <h1>pennies from heaven compilation - various artists (original 1929-1938 version)  </h1><br>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="bloc_artiste" id="ian_svenonius" data-date-created="2010" 

                        data-artist="svenonius" data-band="the make up">
                            <table class="ligne_info">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="artist"><span class="artist_DSC" style="display:none">svenonius</span>
                                        ian svenonius
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="band"><span class="band_DSC" style="display:none">the make up</span>
                                        the make up
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="year">

                                        <span class="year_DSC" style="display:none">        2010</span>
                                        2010</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class="bloc_top_ten">



                                <h1>short novel - by ian  </h1><br>
                                <p><p>&laquo;&nbsp;The Creatures&nbsp;&raquo; were standing in groups 3 or 4 deep, throughout the park at the intersection of 12th street and Hilliard place.</p>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

my Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ligne_open();
    isotope_sort();
});

function ligne_open(){
    $('.bloc_artiste').click(function () {
        var ID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).siblings().children().next().slideUp(500);
        $(this).children().next('div').slideToggle(500, function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(ID).offset().top
            }, 500);
        });

        $(this).siblings().children().next().slideUp(500);
        return false;

    });

    $('.bloc_artiste').hover(function(){
        $('.bloc_artiste').not(this).css('opacity','0.4');
    },function(){
        $('.bloc_artiste').not(this).css('opacity','1');
    });   
}

function isotope_sort(){
    // init Isotope
    var $container = $('#content').isotope({

        layoutMode: 'vertical',
        itemSelector: '.bloc_artiste',     
        sortAscending: {
            artist: true,
            band: true,
            year: true,
            artist_DSC: false,
            band_DSC: false,
            year_DSC: false

        },
        getSortData: {
            artist: '.artist',
            band: '.band',
            year: '.year',
            artist_DSC: '.artist_DSC',
            band_DSC: '.band_DSC',
            year_DSC: '.year_DSC'         
        }
    });

    // bind sort button click
    $('.sorts').on( 'click', 'span', function() {


        var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
        $container.isotope({ sortBy: sortValue });



    }); 
}
```

My problem now is that when I want to slideToggle my children divs, the content is displayed over my other divs instead of pushing down the other divs, like it does when not using isotope.

I think isotope add an absolute position to all my divs, that's why It overlay the other divs.

Does anybody knows a way to make this right ? I've been reading the isotope docs but couldn't find a solution,

Hope someone can help me with this !

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and animate padding-top of isotope container and the amount of padding needs to be the height of the collapsed panel